# What's the best strategy to destroy the bottom sentry on AI Station 404?

Tags: awesomenauts

How to destroy the bottom sentry (B) ?  It seems natural to proceed the same way than for the first sentry (A): let the drones get under its fire, using them as a tank, and shoot it down.  But the drones won't get to this sentry because of the bouncer (right after the first sentry (A)) which will send them to the upper sentry (C).

Flying bots will engage the bottom sentry, but they don't seem to have the "tank" ability, like the regular drones, making them more resistant to sentries' fire.

So how to safely/efficiently deal with it ?  Any idea or suggestion ?

[image: Sentries on AI Station 404]

Comment: I never had a game where B was attacked... We always go straight for end point.

Comment: It would be way tougher to defend the main core if B could be taken down; plus what's the point to put a sentry there if it's not to meant to be an potential access point ? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rarely see a game when that turret is attacked, though it happens on rare occasions. Usually, it is about sending in flying drones and attacking it all together with heroes that are good at sieging enemy turrets.

I know one strategy for one hero, which can be applied to attacking towers in general, I'm sure everybody knows it. It is Lonestar. Get to the turret, launch your bull at it then throw dynamite, make a couple of shots and run back. Repeat when your bull is recharged (I guess, Cattle Recharger ability, that decreases cooldown of bull can be useful here, along with its explosion-on-death). This strategy may have even higher effectiveness if you are accompanied by droids (in this case - flying ones) and/or a hero that has lots of health, like Clunk, or a hero that can prolong the survival of droids (Voltar).

Answer (score 1):

One strategy I use as Raelynn is to use timerift with the drone upgrade, this lets you hide behind a drone while destroying the sentry. This usually works quite well since the other team don't expect trouble on the bottom sentry.

Other than this teamwork and using the flying droids would be the best way of going about it.